# How can I extend ScrollView to default properties in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How can I extend `ScrollView` so that I can just use `MyScrollView` with my default properties?

I would like to replace

```
<ScrollView
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     bounces={false}
     contentContainerStyle={{
                        paddingTop: 50,
                        paddingRight: 33,
                        paddingBottom: 60,
                        paddingLeft: 33
                    }}
>
...
</ScrollView>
```

with my own component by just using

```
<MyScrollView>
...
</MyScrollView>
```

I built my own components but they don't contain other components like Views do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your `MyScrollView` around a ScrollView like such:

```
class MyScrollView extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          paddingTop: 50,
          paddingRight: 33,
          paddingBottom: 60,
          paddingLeft: 33,
        }}
        {...this.props}
      />
  }
};
```

or as a functional component if you do not need state or lifecycle methods:

```
const MyScrollView = props => {
  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      bounces={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingTop: 50,
        paddingRight: 33,
        paddingBottom: 60,
        paddingLeft: 33,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

This way an instance of `MyScrollView` uses your default props, with the ability to override them:

```
<MyScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
  <View />
</MyScrollView>
```

Any child components are passed along with the props to the wrapped ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the child components inside of it like:

```
<MyScrollView>
   <Text>Hello</Text>
</MyScrollView>
```

and then in your MyScrollView component use the children prop to get the views;

```
<ScrollView
 style={{ flex: 1 }}
 showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
 bounces={false}
 contentContainerStyle={{
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingRight: 33,
    paddingBottom: 60,
    paddingLeft: 33
 }}>
   {this.props.children}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks. I took the other answer but this one works great as well.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this default props can be extended for all react native components

```
// In your root or App.jsx file
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'

// Modify the defaultProps of ScrollView
ScrollView.defaultProps = {
  contentContainerStyle: { flexGrow: 1 },
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'handled',
  // And other custom props
}
```